# Can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I concatenate string and float in the following Python code?

```
turkishLira = 7.8
amount = float

print("Welcome to Anilcan\'s money translator!")
amount = input("Please write down the amount you want to translate into TL: ")

total = float(amount) / float(turkishLira)

if amount == 1: print(total)

print("Your value is equal to: ")
print("TL" + total) # can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: I was working on a money calculator that would calculate different types of currencies into the type you chose but my problem is that I get an error at: print("TL" + total). If there is anyone that can help me, please show me what I have to do different.

Comment: `total` is a number. It's impossible to concatenate numbers and strings. It _is_ possible to concatenate two strings, though

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("TL"+str(total))
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the float to a string should solve your problem:

```
print("TL" + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `print("TL", total)`

`+` only works with strings.

Answer (score 0):

In order to concatenate a string and a float/int, you have to do

```
print("TL" + str(total))
```